# C - initialized pointer throws exception about nullptr

Tags: c, function, pointers, initialization, null-pointer

I have a code that intends to find minimal value using pointers, using a function.
The problem is that even though I initialize the pointer while debugging it shows:

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
>   min was nullptr.

At line 37. The code can be seen below:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdio.h"

int tab_min(const int* tab, int size, int *min);

int main()
{
    int limit;
    int tab[100];
    int * ptab = tab;
    int min = 2;
    int *pmin = &min;

    printf("Number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &limit);
    printf("List the elements \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &*(ptab + i)); 
    }
    tab_min(ptab, limit, pmin);

    return 0;
}

int tab_min(const int* tab, int size, int *min) 
{

    if ((tab == NULL) || (size <= 0) || (min = NULL)) 
    {
        return 0; 
    }
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (*(tab + i) < *min) *min = *(tab + i); //Exception is here
        }
    return 0;
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain to me what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: `if ((tab == NULL) || (size <= 0) || (min = NULL)) ` should have a `==`. You are setting `min` to `NULL`.

Comment: `&*(ptab + i)` should be `ptab + i` for clarity.

Comment: Ah well, I did not notice, thank you.

Comment: It is a good idea to write constant value on the left side of the comparison `NULL == min`. This way such a typo will cause a compile time error message.

Comment: C language neither knows anything about exceptions, nor about `nullptr`. Are you using a C++ compiler?

Comment: @WeatherVane you should make this an answer.

Comment: Use a better compiler. Any half-decent compiler will give a message pointing out this bug.

Comment: @VTT No that's a horrible idea from the 1980s. That trick became obsolete in 1989 when Turbo C started to warn for "possible incorrect assignment". Since then, all usable compilers warn for this. The solution is to use a usable compiler, not to write ugly tricks from the early 1980s such as "the Yoda conditions".

Comment: @Lundin Nope, this is a pragmatic approach preventing bugs caused by unpreventable typos. Relying on compiler warning too much is a direct road to farming bugs. Note that [these warnings won't capture this problem in all context](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0ypsWuWrYphcqIk8) and these warnings are actually off by default.

Comment: @VTT This issue was debated in the 1980s and there is an industry consensus that Yoda condition cause more harm than good, period. What you want to prove by linking some C++ code, I have no idea. This question is about C.

Comment: @Lundin Well, my bad, but the [equivalent C code will be almost exactly the same](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1fWOmrs6IVU1ScDw). *"is an industry consensus that Yoda condition cause more harm than good"* citation needed... mcve of such harm would be even beter.

Comment: Isn't even MISRA demanding to put the constant first in such a condition?

Comment: @VTT Anyone writing code like `int is_four = x = 4;` deserve all the bugs they can get. Now lets assume that you write slightly less insane C code instead: `_Bool is_four = x = 4;`. "Suggest parenthesis around assignment". Otherwise, the deal breaker here is that you can write `a = b` - in comes Yoda: `b = a`. How did this solve the bug? We don't always compare against a constant, so we _have_ to rely on static analysis to find this bug. Luckily, every useful compiler on the market does warn for assignment in conditions.

Comment: @Gerhardh No, MISRA demands that 1) comparisons must be explicitly boolean, i.e `if(ptr == NULL)` rather than `if(ptr)`, and  2) the result of an assignment expression should never be used. So any MISRA checker will catch this bug, just as any half-decent compiler. I think pretty much any tool on the market apart from MSVC will catch the bug.

Comment: @Lundin There is nothing special about that code. `_Bool` wasn't even a thing until C99 and regular `int` are still widely used as Boolean values today and not going away anytime soon. [Here is another example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RwUUbHhM4pCQJtET), not involving bool substitution. If `b` is a constant value then writing `b = a` would catch the bug. If it is not then Yoda conditions are not applicable. However you can not conclude them bad anyhow because of this.

Comment: @VTT Simply don't write trash code with 3 operators on a single line - that never ends well for _any_ operators in the C language. If you write trash code, it is not surprise if the result is also trash. I'm done with this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical error is that `if ((tab == NULL) || (size <= 0) || (min = NULL))` assign var min to NULL.

if you need to record the minimum value, you can use pointer address as parameter

```
int tab_min(const int* tab, int size, int **min);
```

and

```
if (*(tab + i) < **min) *min = (tab + i);
```

and call like

```
tab_min(ptab, limit, &pmin);
```

Thanks @Gerhardh for pointing out my mistake

Comment: I think you have ignored *min = *(tab + i); this is wrong no matter whether you record the position the min, as min is 2, *min is 0x00000002, which cannot be access

Comment: Yes, I misunderstand